# How to get first true value of an object and return the corresponding key?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an object as :

```
var myObj = {called: false, invited: true, interviewed: false, offer: false}
```

How can I find the first value that is `true` and then return the corresponding key ?

I want to create a function that, given an object that is always the same structure, returns me the key of the first `true` value.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you know that the property collection is not ordered ? If you are expecting a rules of priority there, it will not works.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myObj = {called: false, invited: true, interviewed: false, offer: false};

const getTrueKey = obj => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj[key]) return key;
  };
  return undefined;
};

console.log(getTrueKey(myObj));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler solution to the question

```js
const myObj = {called: false, invited: true, interviewed: false, offer: false};


const getFirstTruthyItem = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).find((i) => obj[i] === true);

console.log(getFirstTruthyItem(myObj));
```

Comment: In JavaScript, it's bit misleading to name the function `getFirstTruthyItem` as you're strictly comparing with the keyword `true`. The context being that "truthy" has a wider meaning than `=== true` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to make more simpler.

```
const myObj = {called: false, invited: true, interviewed: false, offer: false};

console.log(Object.keys(myObj).find(key => myObj[key])) // Output: invited
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let key in myObj) {
    if(myObj[key]) return key;
}
```